# Data serialization in C?

Tags: c, serialization, floating-point

I have this structure which I want to write to a file:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* egg;
    unsigned long sausage;
    long bacon;
    double spam;
} order;
```

This file must be binary and must be readable by any machine that has a
C99 compiler.

I looked at various approaches to this matter such as ASN.1, XDR, XML,
ProtocolBuffers and many others, but none of them fit my requirements:

- small
- simple
- written in **C**

I decided then to make my own data protocol. I could handle the
following representations of **integer** types:

- unsigned
- signed in *one's complement*
- signed in *two's complement*
- signed in *sign and magnitude*

in a valid, simple and clean way (impressive, no?). However, the
**real** types are being a pain now.

How should I read `float` and `double` from a byte stream? The standard
says that bitwise operators (at least `&`, `|`, `<<` and `>>`) are for
**integer** types only, which left me without hope. The only way I could
think was:

```
int sign;
int exponent;
unsigned long mantissa;

order my_order;

sign = read_sign();
exponent = read_exponent();
mantissa = read_mantissa();

my_order.spam = sign * mantissa * pow(10, exponent);
```

but that doesn't seem really efficient. I also could not find a
description of the representation of `double` and `float`. How should
one proceed before this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be as portable as possible with floats you can use frexp and ldexp:

```
void WriteFloat (float number)
{
  int exponent;
  unsigned long mantissa;

  mantissa = (unsigned int) (INT_MAX * frexp(number, &exponent);

  WriteInt (exponent);
  WriteUnsigned (mantissa);
}

float ReadFloat ()
{
  int exponent = ReadInt();
  unsigned long mantissa = ReadUnsigned();

  float value = (float)mantissa / INT_MAX;

  return ldexp (value, exponent);
}
```

The Idea behind this is, that ldexp, frexp and INT_MAX are standard C. Also the precision of an unsigned long is usually at least as high as the width of the mantissa (no guarantee, but it is a valid assumption and I don't know a single architecture that is different here).

Therefore the conversion works without precision loss. The division/multiplication with INT_MAX may loose a bit of precision during conversion, but that's a compromise one can live with.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! `frexp` seem to be just what I needed!

Comment: after reading your post a couple of times, I began to wonder if there isn't an more efficient way. Teh IEEE-754 format carries a exponent of a base 10. If this is teh format in my machine, extracting a base 2 log would trigger a unnecessary conversion, no?

Comment: `INT_MAX` is implementation defined, so it's not safe for decoding to rely on it.

Comment: Maybe it's ok to use `2147483647` which is the least `INT_MAX` acceptable in Standard C.

Comment: @kalzer.se: if you don't agree with me about portability, why don'you propose a portable way to solve the issue?

Comment: Scaling by `INT_MAX` introduces unnnessary rounding errors.  `INT_MAX + 1.0` is better.  Rather than `unsigned long, unsigned`, use one.  Suggest `unsigned long` and then use `(LONG_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0f` for scaling.

Comment: @u0b34a0f6ae  [Maybe it's ok to use 2147483647 which is the least INT_MAX acceptable in Standard C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608370/data-serialization-in-c/5608466#comment9651330_5608466).  `INT_MAX is at _least_ 32767.  Could be 2147483647, 9223372036854775807, or others.  Using `INT_MAX` breaks portability between systems here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IEEE-754 why not access the `float` or `double` as a `unsigned short` or `unsigned long` and save the floating point data as a series of bytes, then re-convert the "specialized" `unsigned short` or `unsigned long` back to a `float` or `double` on the other side of the transmission ... the bit-data would be preserved, so you should end-up with the same floating point number after transmission.

Comment: Acessing it as a long seem a undefined behaviour, however, casting it to a array of unsigned chars should be ok. However, is it guaranteed that `double` and `float` will have the same representation on every machine?

Comment: If they are complying with the IEEE-754 standard, then the only issue should be endianess ... so you should store those values in some-type of consistent endian format so that you always interpret your byte-array as either little-endian or big-endian no matter what the platform is.  The same would be true for a cast to a `unsigned short` or `unsigned long`.

Comment: Endianness already shows us that teh representations may be different. This seem inconsistent.

Comment: BTW, after thinking about this, rather than a cast, maybe you should use a `union` data-type that contains both a `float` and a `unsigned short`, or a `double` and a `unsigned long` (or `long long` if that is 64-bits wide on your platform).

Comment: I'm not sure how you're going to get away from endian problems for multi-byte datatypes. For instance networking applications have to deal with that all the time and they've standardized on big-endian.

Comment: **Integer** types have well defined data representations, **real** types do not. =o/

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting to serialize your data into a format that can be deserialized without having to know how the data was originally serialized?

Comment: I need to serialize data without knowing how it is represented in memory (as teh standard does not specify this). Deserialization will, of course, need how teh data is written on teh file.

Comment: Oh, integers have well defined representation, floats were teh real problem but that was solved! Thanks! Maybe i will put my lib on sourceforge so teh poor souls needing this will not have to worry anymoar.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C99 you can output real numbers in portable hex using `%a`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that! However, I need binary representations and printf is just too heavy for me

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses Nils Pipenbrinck's method but I have changed a few details that I think help to ensure real C99 portability.  This solution lives in an imaginary context where `encode_int64` and `encode_int32` etc already exist.

```
#include <stdint.h>     
#include <math.h>                                                         

#define PORTABLE_INTLEAST64_MAX ((int_least64_t)9223372036854775807) /* 2^63-1*/             

/* NOTE: +-inf and nan not handled. quickest solution                            
 * is to encode 0 for !isfinite(val) */                                          
void encode_double(struct encoder *rec, double val) {                            
    int exp = 0;                                                                 
    double norm = frexp(val, &exp);                                              
    int_least64_t scale = norm*PORTABLE_INTLEAST64_MAX;                          
    encode_int64(rec, scale);                                                    
    encode_int32(rec, exp);                                                      
}                                                                                

void decode_double(struct encoder *rec, double *val) {                           
    int_least64_t scale = 0;                                                     
    int_least32_t exp = 0;                                                       
    decode_int64(rec, &scale);                                                   
    decode_int32(rec, &exp);                                                     
    *val = ldexp((double)scale/PORTABLE_INTLEAST64_MAX, exp);                    
}
```

This is still not a real solution, `inf` and `nan` can not be encoded. Also notice that both parts of the double carry sign bits.

`int_least64_t` is guaranteed by the standard (`int64_t` *is not*), and we use the least perimissible maximum for this type to scale the double. The encoding routines accept `int_least64_t` but will have to reject input that is larger than 64 bits for portability, the same for the 32 bit case.

Comment: Instead of `2^63-1` ( which once converted to a `double` loses precision and likely becomes 2^63), use `norm*9223372036854775808.0 /* 2^63 */`.

Comment: I like the idea of _not_ using `INT_MAX` here, but least fixed sized integer types.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard doesn't define a representation for floating point types. Your best bet would be to convert them to IEEE-754 format and store them that way. [Portability of binary serialization of double/float type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733147/portability-of-binary-serialization-of-double-float-type-in-c/4733588#4733588) may help you there.

Note that the C standard also doesn't specify a format for integers. While most computers you're likely to encounter will use a normal two's-complement representation with only endianness to be concerned about, it's also possible they would use a one's-complement or sign-magnitude representation, and both signed and unsigned ints may contain padding bits that don't contribute to the value.

Comment: I read this carefully and implemented every possibility teh standard allows! Thanks!