# Recording set of points in openGL ES like the GLPaint example

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, playback

I am currently trying to generate a similar affect as the playback animation from Apple's GLPaint example code. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642067/what-kind-of-data-does-apple-use-on-glpaint-example) stackoverflow post, and I am also trying to do something similar, except I am not sure how to go about capturing the animated strokes as data in the first place. How do you capture the CGPoints on screen?