# Can I save a structure in a file, e.g txt.file?

Tags: c

Can I save a structure in a file, for example to a txt?. And also if I can, would it be possible to reopen it and get the data back?

Maybe something like this:

```
struct guest
{
        int tel;
        char name[20];
        char country[20];
} ;

int main()
{

        record.tel=231231;
        strcpy(record.name, "Raju");
        record.country= China;
```

Comment: yes, you can...

Comment: You can - just define a standard way to store it and then retrieve it using the same method.

Comment: You can.  But you most likely don't want to.  You want to store this stuff in a database instead.  If you haven't any database handy, pick sqlite.

Comment: use `fwrite`, `fread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can. You have two choises.

1) As a binary that is not portable.

```
//  Writing to a file inticaded by fp ...
fwrite( &record, sizeof(struct guest), 1, fp );

// Reading from a file inticaded by fp ... 
fread( &record, sizeof(struct guest), 1, fp );
```

2) As a text, which is portable.

```
//  Writing to a file inticaded by fp ...
fprintf( fp, "%d %20s %20s", record.tel, record.name, record.country );

// Reading from a file inticaded by fp ... 
fscanf( fp, "%d %s %s", &record.tel, &record.name, &record.country );
```

With first choice (binary) you can read directly from the file, see an example [here](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c39.htm), if you save it as a text you will have to read line by line and give values ​​manually in the fields of the struct.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
fprintf(file, "%d %20s %20s\n", record.tel, record.name, record.country);
fscanf(file, "%d %20s %20s\n", &record.tel, &record.name, &record.country);
```

UPD: if `name` and/or `country` may contain spaces, use the following to read back:

```
char blank[1];

fscanf(file, "%d ", &record.tel);
fread(record.name, 20, 1, file);
fread(blank, 1, 1, file); // assert(blank[0] == ' ');
fread(record.country, 20, 1, file);
fread(blank, 1, 1, file); // assert(blank[0] == '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Functionality you describe is called **serialization**.
There are a lot of information in the internet.
for ex. refer to the:
[Data serialization in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608370/data-serialization-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

If its your first time use  `fprintf() / fscanf()` and no `printf() / scanf()`