# When serializing, why multiply mantissa by INT_MAX before casting to unsigned int?

Tags: c

I want to understand float serialization better. Why in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5608466/7933478) do they multiple the mantissa by INT_MAX before casting to unsigned int?

```
void WriteFloat (float number)
{
  int exponent;
  unsigned long mantissa;

  mantissa = (unsigned int) (INT_MAX * frexp(number, &exponent);

  WriteInt (exponent);
  WriteUnsigned (mantissa);
}

float ReadFloat ()
{
  int exponent = ReadInt();
  unsigned long mantissa = ReadUnsigned();

  float value = (float)mantissa / INT_MAX;

  return ldexp (value, exponent);
}
```

Comment: FYI, this is a bad way to serialize floating-point values. As long as `float` is a binary floating-point format, either `ldexpf(mantissa, FLT_MANT_DIG)` or `scalbnf(mantissa, FLT_MANT_DIG)` will give the significand as an integer. (“Significand” is the preferred term; “mantissa” is an old word for the fraction part of a logarithm.)

Comment: Dylan Landry, [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5608466/7933478) uses `unsigned long mantissa;` instead of `unsigned mantissa;` for no apprent reasosn.  All-in-all, that answer has mutiple problems (not your fault).  IMO, not a good answer.

Comment: Dylan Landry, serializing floating point values as integers also incur problems with [NAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), +/- infinity and -0.0.  These are not addressed in the example code.  Good serializing requires more than what you are reviewing.  IMO, the simplest, good serialization is `printf("%a", fp);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I did some research on the `%a` approach and went with that, it was easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`frexp()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/frexp) returns a 'normalized' value in the range (±)[0.5 – 1.0). Clearly, this is not a range that can be properly represented in a variable of *integral* type (a simple cast of that value would **always** yield zero, as the range does *not include* `±1.0`), so it has to be 'denormalized' (stretched) into a range that *is* fully representable.

Multiplying by `INT_MAX` will give (nearly) the greatest precision possible (assuming `int` and `unsigned long` have the same bit-width)**<sup>†</sup>**, without overflowing the range of the destination type (including the possibility of storing the representation of a negative value in that *unsigned* integer).

---

Note: One *could* get more precision by storing the sign of the normalized fraction, then subtracting 0.5 from its **absolute value**, re-applying the sign and multiplying by `2.0 * INT_MAX` (I *think* this will be safe) … but the precision gain (1 bit) is likely not worth the extra effort in coding (and decoding) the stored value.

---

**<sup>†</sup>** On many platforms, the `int` and `long` types are the same size; however, this is not required so, as mentioned in the comments, using `LONG_MAX` as the multiplier/divisor would potentially offer greater precision; however, that *may* be overkill, depending on how many bits of mantissa there are in the source. If it's an IEEE-754 single-precision `float`, it will have 23 bits, so a 16-bit `int` type would lose out, but a 64-bit `LONG_MAX` would be over-cooking.

Comment: Disagree with "Multiplying by `INT_MAX` will give the greatest precision possible,".  Multiplying by `INT_MAX + 1.0` or even `LONG_MAX + 1.0` (with 16-bit `int`) will give greater precision.

Comment: @chux On `LONG_MAX` - see edit. On the `+ 1` - wouldn't that (potentially) cause overflow/underflow issues for negative value data?

Comment: .. or for data that are at the *actual* +/- 1.0 limit?

Comment: `(±)[0.5 – 1.0]` is incorrect.  S/b `(±)[0.5 – 1.0)`.  Thus I see no overflow issue.

Comment: @chux Thanks for the correction (I wasn't actually sure, so I checked the Standard and edited my answer to use the correct range.) But using `INT_MAX + 1` isn't going to add that much precision, really - especially if we have 32-bit ints. However, you are technically correct, and the 16-bit int platforms will be awkward here.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a Standard C `_I32_MAX` constant.

Comment: Another benefit of `INT_MAX plus 1` is that it is a power-of-2, thus incurring no rounding error in the  `INT_MAX_PLUS1 * frexp(number, &exponent)` multiplication.  I'd use `#define INT_MAX_PLUS1 ((INT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0f)` and `frexpf()` instead of `frexp()`.

Comment: I've read the value of `INT_MAX` depends on the C implementation. Is it correct that if the serializing and unserializing machine's value for `INT_MAX` differ, that the float values with vary drastically? Is this likely? Sorry for adding on questions.

Comment: @DylanLandry Yes - that *could* be a very nasty problem. A fixed multiplier (like 2^24 for 23-bit mantissa) would likely be better. But, as with the comments from chux, that's maybe more of a discussion for the original (linked) answer.