# What's the best way to serialize a double to a string and back again?

Tags: java, c++, c++11, serialization

I have a Java program that launches a C++ program with `ProcessBuilder`, and reads the output from the C++ application as an string. The data is a mix of datatypes, where I'm serializing everything as an string via `std::cout`, like this:

```
void write_data(int x) {
    std::cout << "int:" << x << std::endl;
}

void write_data(double x) {
    std::cout << "double:" << x << std::endl;
}
```

On the Java side I'm doing something like:

```
String line = readLineFromSubProcess();
String[] parts = line.split(":");

if (parts[0].equals("double")) {
  return Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
}
```

However, since I'm reading sensors data I'm concerned about the loss of precision on the floating point values. I'm in direct control on the serialization format.

How can I write a `double` value from C++ to `std::cout` in a way that reading it from Java produces exactly the same double value?

Comment: Is there any way to get the sensor data out in an integral fashion? Else serialise it with the precision (or accuracy) that the manufacturer of the sensor specifies it has.

Comment: The data comes from a custom in-house database, there are some apps that write doubles to this database, and I need to read them back to send to a 3rd party monitoring Java program. All I have is this double value. So far I've been using the naive `std::cout << x` approach since its easy to read on the screen for us.

Comment: Given that they come from a serialised source, when you read them in store the precision they come with and then write them out again with that same precision.

Comment: @Niall I don't know what precision those values were written with, and I don't think there is someone around here who can even answer that question... Since a double is an IEEE 754 I was thinking more on the lines of serializing the raw bytes, reading them from Java and building the original bits again.

Comment: You could read your doubles in java using c++ with jni interface, do some preprocessing and return to java frontend. If you are concerned about formatting problems - loosing precision, then maybe write to cout in binary format - for example uuencode binary double data. But I would do some heavy testing, to find examples of data with lost precision.

Comment: It would take some testing (and may be implementation specific, endianess issues etc.), but the serialised raw bytes could work.

Comment: Maybe write the ieee representation to binary and read that? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733147/portability-of-binary-serialization-of-double-float-type-in-c

Comment: just to understand - you are using c++ code to read a database and then a java layer on top of this to propagate to the 3rd party app?

Comment: erm - why not use java to talk to the database and forgo the c++ layer?

Comment: @Nim It's a DB some colleagues made, and we don't have Java bindings, just some adhoc C++ API.

Comment: ah okay, you could always do the hacky convert to hex string, then use `ByteBuffer` to rebuild from hex... still will need to handle endianess though...

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've decided to go with is to `reinterpret_cast` the `double` to an `int64_t` and the `float` to an `int32_t`, and using partial template specialization just for this two data types. I'm still missing the endianess conversion but since everything here is little endian I think I'll be fine:

```
template <typename T>
void write_data(T x) {
    std::cout << get_type_name<T>() << ":" << x << std::endl;
}

template<>
void write_data<double>(double x) {
    union {
        double d;
        int64_t i;
    } n;
    n.d = x;
    std::cout << "double_as_int64:" << n.i << std::endl; 
}

template<>
void write_data<float>(double x) {
    union {
        float f;
        int32_t i;
    } n;
    n.f = x;
    std::cout << "float_as_int32:" << n.i << std::endl; 
}
```

I'm not literally doing a `reinterpret_cast` since my compiler (GCC) gives me a [warning about aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163126/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-warning), which has to do with the compiler switches we're using here:

> dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules

On the Java side I'm doing:

```
String line = readLineFromSubProcess();
String[] parts = line.split(":");

if (parts[0].equals("double")) {
  return Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
} else if (parts[0].equals("double_as_int64") {
  return Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.parseLong(parts[1]));
} else if (parts[0].equals("float_as_int32") {
  return Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
}
```

Which is what [Google Protocol Buffers are doing under the hood](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.java?r=530&spec=svn606#328).

Comment: Warning: While this trick will usually work, it is undefined behavior in C++ to store in a union as one type and read from it as another.  This technique is correct in C, but in C++ it could bite you, most likely due to compiler optimizations that make incorrect assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said, there are two options, if you care about readability and need to print doubles then:

**Method 1:**  *(readable)*

```
#include <limits>

void double_to_string(double the_double, int offset_to_max)
{
        typedef std::numeric_limits<double> doublelimit;

        // ready to transfer
        std::cout.precision(doublelimit::digits10 + offset_to_max);
        std::cout << the_double << std::endl;
}

// Back to double
double cstring_to_double(const char *s)
{
        return std::atof(s);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        double the_double = 0.10000000000000002;
        //double the_double = 0.1; 
        int offset = 2;

        double_to_string(the_double, offset);
}
```

This way, doubles printed will have aliasing using full precision (17). I recomend using 17 since the default will always try to round. Either way, a full correct print using this method will require a more powerful library.

**Method 2:** *(binary)*

Just memcpy the value, using and int64 is fine, double can store 53 bits max:

```
template<typename T, typename H = int64_t>
H write_data(T x) 
{
    H i;
    // Can we hold the data?
    if (sizeof(T) > sizeof(H)) assert(false); // or write some error procesing
    // Now take the lower size of the two.
    memcpy(&i, &x, sizeof(H) > sizeof(T) ? sizeof(T) : sizeof(H));

    return i;
}

// union version
template<typename T, typename H = int64_t>
H write_data_u(T x)
{
    // Can we hold the data?
    if (sizeof(T) > sizeof(H)) assert(false); // or write some error procesing

    union {
        T d;
        H i;
    } n;

    n.d = x;

    return n.i;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    double the_double = 0.10000000000000001;
    int64_t double_holder = write_data<double, int64_t>(the_double);

    // Binary data as decimal string: ready to transfer the string, remember to convert to big_endian first if you transfer the binary representation.
    std::cout << "double_as_int64:" << double_holder << std::endl;

    // Back to double (we know int64_t holds a double so we dont care about the remaining bits)
    double back_to_double = write_data<int64_t, double>(double_holder);
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 2);
    std::cout << "back_to_double:" << back_to_double << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Will this help?

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
```

Please see the examples at:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will follow this rule in the future.