# Find float type's memory format

Tags: c++, floating-point

How to find the memory format of `float` and `double` types?

I mean the numbers of bits for sign, exponent, and fraction.

Comment: The format for `float` and `double` is *usually* IEEE-754 but this isn't guaranteed. You can check if it is using [`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559). `std::numeric_limits` will allow you to check many properties of your types, but this does not include the exact memory layout.

Comment: That should be documented by your implementation.

Comment: Have you tried googling for `float memory format`? These types are supported directly by CPUs and follow specific standards. The very first Google result is [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). If a CPU doesn't follow the IEEE 754 standard, you should check the CPU's documentation.

Comment: *Why* do you care about the memory format of floats? Do you have a specific problem, eg endianess, differences between ARM and x86? Serialization problems?

Comment: @NathanOliver so, I should try to find the cpu id of the system and then look up the documentation, and then write a function that returns the floating point format, depending on the cpu id? I thought some library would have done that....

Comment: @rxu why would a library bother? It's the compiler's job to handle such things. The code would run anyway. If you want to read the sign, fraction etc, use the appropriate functions. That's not what you asked though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to save floating point numbers to hard disk and wonder if there is a good way to make the file cross platform. Or at least, warn the user if the file's floating point format doesn't match the system's floating point format.

Comment: @rxu that's a *completely* different problem. Why do you ecare about the *memory* layout though?? Shouldn't you be asking about streams and endianess? That *is* well defined and implemented in the standard language itself. Again, have you encountered a problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I am saving float to file in binary, and then reading float from file in binary. If the float memory layout of the machine that writes the file and the machine that reads the file are different... will that be ok? I don't know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733147/portability-of-binary-serialization-of-double-float-type-in-c

Comment: @rxu see the update at the bottom of my answer to address use case. You should mention it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save floating point numbers to disk in a cross platform manner, look up my github project

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/ieee754

I've also put in functions for reading binary integers portably, as it is slightly more involved than appears at first sight.

If you want to test memory format, you need to create floats with certain strategic values, then query the bit patterns. Zero should be all bits zero and a special case, unless you're on weird and wonderful hardware. 1 and -1 should differ by one bit, which is you sign bit. 2 and 1 should differ in the exponent, and testing powers of two should tell you the exponent bits and when they run out. Test powers of powers of two for speed.

You can then get the mantissa by storing 1 off a power of 2, e.g 3, 7 and so on.

By probing it you can build up a memory pattern, but it's almost always IEEE 754.

Comment: Free for any use. Mathematical routines like that can't be patented.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean the numbers of bits for sign, exponent, and fraction.

You can use `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` to get mantissa bits, `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` to get the sign bits.

You and deduct their sum from `sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT` to guess the exponent digits, but this may not be correct if the type has padding. This is typical for `long double` for example.

> Find float type's memory format

Of course, not only the number of bits matter, but also the order. These functions do not help you with that. They also assume that `std::numeric_limits<T>::radix == 2`.

For the exact format, you will have to consult the manual of the cpu architechture.

---

> I want to save floating point numbers to hard disk and wonder if there is a good way to make the file cross platform.

The most typical solution is to convert the floating point to a textual representation when saving to disk: `0x1.8p+0`. It's not most efficient, but it is portable (although, you do have to decide what character encoding the file is going to use, and if that is not native to the system, there needs to be a conversion).